# How to Solve this keyerror : Value based partial slicing on non-monotonic DatetimeIndexes with non-existing keys is not allowed

Tags: python, data-science

I'm taking a data science course, and there is one exercise that instructs me to do this:

Plot the rolling 30 day average against the Close Price for Bank Of America's stock for the year 2008

this is code from the suggested solution but still not work for me :

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
BAC['Close'].loc['2009-01-01':'2010-01-01'].rolling(window=30).mean().plot(label='30 Day Avg')
BAC['Close'].loc['2009-01-01':'2010-01-01'].plot(label='BAC CLOSE')
plt.legend()
```

the error message :

Value based partial slicing on non-monotonic DatetimeIndexes with non-existing keys is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I took the same course and faced the same issue. Here comes the solution (for me):

Error suggests that there might be an issue with the indexing of the DataFrame. (notice the 'non-monotonic' word...)
Thus, I check the Index order:

```
# Check if the index is sorted
if not BAC.index.is_monotonic_increasing:
 BAC = BAC.sort_index()

plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
BAC['Close'].loc['2009-01-01':'2010-01-01'].rolling(window=30).mean().plot(label='30 Day Avg')
BAC['Close'].loc['2009-01-01':'2010-01-01'].plot(label='BAC CLOSE')
plt.legend()
```

If you do not want to use `is_monotonic_increasing()`; you can just sort the index by `sort_index()` before calculating and plotting the Moving Average:
`BAC = BAC.sort_index()`

plot: [sorted BAC, Moving Average Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYyNy.png)

Answer (score -1):

```
k_neighbors = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
weights = np.linspace(0.005, 0.25, 10)

# Create the pipeline
pipe = make_pipeline(SMOTE(), LogisticRegression())

# Set up the GridSearchCV
param_grid = {
    'smote__k_neighbors': k_neighbors,
    'logisticregression__class_weight': weights
}

gsc = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='f1', cv=3)
grid_result = gsc.fit(X_train, Y_train)

# Print the best parameters and best score
print("Best Parameters: ", grid_result.best_params_)
print("Best F1 Score: ", grid_reenter code heresult.best_score_)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).